# File not found error in java, file is in my project folder?

Tags: java, file-not-found

The file is in my project, and named correctly, I am quite new to JAVA. Any hints would be appreciated, TIA.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExceptionsAndCarryOn {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(new File("Numbers.txt"));
        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers: ");

        int [] numbers = new int [5];
        int i = 0;
        while(UserInput.hasNextInt()){
            numbers[i++] = UserInput.nextInt();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            sum += numbers[i];
        System.out.println(sum);

        UserInput.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: how are you executing the program?

Comment: Just in the IDE

Comment: and where have you put the text file?

Comment: @C.Roberts you told user user to type "Please enter the numbers: " but not taking the input. Not an error but you can modify it.

Comment: are you sure Numbers.txt is in your current folder?

Comment: the file is most definitely in the current folder

Comment: try to use the absolute path of file.

Comment: what do you mean by 'current folder'? besides java code in src folder? or at project root folder?

Comment: By *current folder* do you mean the src folder or the build/classes folder?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: its in the src folder, and I'm using eclipse mars 3.2

Comment: try using this:
"src/Numbers.txt"

Comment: Still not working

Comment: put it parallel to the src folder and it shall work.

Comment: When you're using relative paths, you've to be careful of which directory is your current working directory. When you're telling the system to look just for 'Numbers.txt', it'll look for it in the current working directory. When you're running your project straight from the IDE, the current working directory is set to the project folder (the same place that contains your bin and src folders). That's where it's looking for numbers.txt. So if you put it in the src folder, you need to update the relative path accordingly.

Comment: Thank you all for your help/advice, got it working now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the file Numbers.txt in the project folder , parallel to the src folder. not inside the src folder.

That will solve your problem . Since you are not providing the fully qualified name (absolute path) . the JRE will assume that the file should be in the project folder from where your application is being run.

You can put the file in any folder and use fully qualified names like:

```
   Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(new File("D://Sunit//Numbers.txt"));
```

Answer (score 4):

one of these can be the cause of the issue

1. file is in the current working directory
2. file has that specific name and extension
3. if you're using windows enable the "show extension for hidden files" property from the settings. otherwise it could happen that Numbers.txt.txt is the actual name

Answer (score 2):

You stated that the file is in your project/src folder. That is where the source files are present, not executed.

When the .java files are compiled, the bytecodes (.class files) are stored in the build/classes directory. You may keep the Numbers.txt there, but it will be deleted once you give the clean and build option.

You have two alternatives:

1. Change the path in the code to "../../src/Numbers.txt"
2. Move the Numbers.txt anywhere and give the absolute path.